# Intermittent ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

We encountered an issue where a series of git requests over ssh would *sometimes* fail with 
`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

There are many examples on SE/SF of structural problems (tcp-wrappers, permission on key files).

Our problem was: What is a likely cause of intermittent connection failures with this message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our issue appeared to have been caused by a moderately high number of incoming requests.

As soon as the number of unauthenticated connections goes over the sshd:MaxStartUps parameter,
sshd starts rejecting those connections.

The solution lies in modifying `MaxStartups` in `sshd_config`

Comment: It can also indicate a brute force attack, please make use of /etc/hosts.{allow,deny} files to limit connections.                                                                       http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/10/using-tcp-wrappers-to-secure-linux.html

Comment: @AndrewMcGlashan it depends on the definition of **moderately high number** in this context.  I think we had a Jenkins host checking out repositories from our git server, all within our own network.  This host could very well handle the bursts, so we increased that limit.